# Launchd prevents script from changing desktop picture

Tags: python, applescript, launchd

I have a little script I'm working on to retrieve a new picture from http://reddit.com/r/wallpapers daily, and set that as my wallpaper. When I call the script from the command line, it works beautifully. But as soon as I try and setup a launch daemon it will save the picture, but the desktop does not change. I expect it has something to do with the scope, but I have no idea where to start.

Code:

```
SCRIPT = """/usr/bin/osascript<<END
tell application "Finder"
set desktop picture to POSIX file "%s"
end tell
END"""

file_path = /some/file/the/script/downloaded.jpg

subprocess.Popen(SCRIPT%file_path, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be right about the reason, however I've seen strange things with "POSIX file" commands inside an application tell block of code. "POSIX file" is an applescript command. You will find it in the "standard additions" applescript dictionary not the Finder's applescript dictionary. As such it could be a problem when you tell the Finder to perform that command because the Finder doesn't know that command.

A general applescript rule is that you shouldn't tell an application to do something that's not in its applescript dictionary... strange things can happen if you do. And you have a strange thing happening so step 1 is to make sure your code is as clean as possible.

So here's something to try. As mentioned I'm just guessing because I've seen problems with this before so it's worth a shot. Try this as your applescript code.

```
set p to POSIX file "%s"
tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to p
```